# Java script split function is not working for each loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am facing a problem that I am getting the data from the Mongodb database and I am trying to show for each employee its details. 
I am using the split function to split the data of one row with reference of ","
It is working fine for one employee but for all other employee it is repeating the data of first employee. 
I mean for 1 employee it is working fine for second employee it shows nothing but instead it repeats the data of first emplyee in the first emplyee section. This is my code. Please check what is wrong.

```
 {{# each employees}}

                <p id="Institution" style="display: none">
                    {{InstitutionAssociates}}
                </p>
                <script>
                    var i;
                    var str=document.getElementById("Institution").innerHTML;
                    array = str.split(',');
                    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
                        var para = document.createElement("li");
                        var node = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
                        para.appendChild(node);
                        var element = document.getElementById("InstitutionAssociates");
                        element.appendChild(para);}
                </script>






                       <td>{{#if InstitutionAssociates}}

                    <ul id="InstitutionAssociates">

                    </ul>
            </td>
            {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
```

Comment: `{{# each` - you mean to `{{#each`

Comment: Yes, It is the same